# Linux Find directories that don’t containing a specific type of file?

Tags: linux, find

I'm new to Linux and I want to find directories which doesn't contain a type of file, like `*.jpg`.

Is there a parameter of the find command to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. You would have to first determine the type of every file in the directory (and do subdirectories count?) and you cannot depend on a file extension since they don't really exist in Linux.

You would need a script that checks every file in the directory using the `file` command, which will be fairly reliable in determining the file type, and return true only if every file is not a JPEG. This can be done but you'll need to write a script for the check and you will need to tailor the find command to specify which directories you want checked, e.g. should foo/, foo/bar, foo/bar/a, foo/bar/b, foo/bar/a/c all be checked?

Comment: Thank you anyway

Comment: @Daydreamer067 Please consider accepting this answer if it meets your needs, even if it is not what you wanted to hear. Accepting the answer will make the question/answer combo drift up to the top in future searches.